# Function to Combine 2 PDFs getting timeout error

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is my function that I'm using to combine two PDFs into one (this is happening within a larger forEach loop but I didn't include it because I don't want to overcomplicate my question).

I have noted all the console log outputs, which seem to indicate the PDF files are valid and they load successfully. However, the end result of the function is to create a new file called "combined.pdf" and this is not happening. I am getting this error after I run my function: "ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined"

```
    // ****** FUNCTION 1 ******
    async function loadPDF(pdfBytes) {
      try {
        const loadedPdf = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
        console.log(`PDF loaded successfully`);
        return loadedPdf;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error loading PDF:`, error);
        return null;
      }
    }

    // ****** MAIN FUNCTION ******
    async function combinePDFsIntoOne () {

      const cdnjs = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib@1.16.0/dist/pdf-lib.min.js';
      eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText());

      const pdfFile1 = pdf;
      const pdfFile2 = pdfP2FileName;

      console.log(typeof pdfFile1) //object
      console.log(pdfFile1)
      /*
      { toString: [Function],
      getName: [Function],
      getBytes: [Function],
      setName: [Function],
      getContentType: [Function],
      setContentType: [Function],
      setBytes: [Function],
      getDataAsString: [Function],
      setDataFromString: [Function],
      isGoogleType: [Function],
      getAllBlobs: [Function],
      setContentTypeFromExtension: [Function],
      copyBlob: [Function],
      getAs: [Function] }
      */

      console.log(typeof pdfFile2) //object
      console.log(pdfFile2)
      /*
      { toString: [Function],
      getName: [Function],
      getBytes: [Function],
      setName: [Function],
      getContentType: [Function],
      setContentType: [Function],
      setBytes: [Function],
      getDataAsString: [Function],
      setDataFromString: [Function],
      isGoogleType: [Function],
      getAllBlobs: [Function],
      setContentTypeFromExtension: [Function],
      copyBlob: [Function],
      getAs: [Function] }
      */

      // Read files as "Binary Strings"
      const pdfBytes1 = new Uint8Array(pdfFile1.getBytes()); 
      const pdfBytes2 = new Uint8Array(pdfFile2.getBytes()); 

      // Create new pdf
      const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();

      // // Load the first and second PDFs
      // const firstPDF = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes1);
      // const secondPDF = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes2);

      // Try loading the first PDF
      const firstPDF = await loadPDF(pdfBytes1); // PDF loaded successfully
      console.log(typeof firstPDF);
      if (!firstPDF) {
        console.log(`Error loading first PDF ${typeof firstPDF}`);
      }
      // Try loading the second PDF
      const secondPDF = await loadPDF(pdfBytes2); // PDF loaded successfully
      if (!secondPDF) {
        console.log(`Error loading second PDF ${typeof secondPDF}`);
      }

      // Get pages to import
      const firstPDFPages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(firstPDF, firstPDF.getPageIndices());
      const secondPDFPages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(secondPDF, secondPDF.getPageIndices());

      // Add pages to the PDF
      firstPDFPages.forEach((page) => pdfDoc.addPage(page));
      secondPDFPages.forEach((page) => pdfDoc.addPage(page));

      const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
      const newBlob = Utilities.newBlob(Array.from(pdfBytes), 'application/pdf');

      newBlob.setName('combined.pdf');
      holdingFolder.createFile(newBlob);

    };

    try {
      await combinePDFsIntoOne ();
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(`Error is: ${err}`) // Error is: ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I found the bug! All I had to do was define this variable:

```
const setTimeout = function (f, t) {
  Utilities.sleep(t);
  return f();
}
```

Thanks again to Tanaike for being such a great resource for Google Apps Script!